# How to fix certain inputs in an equation to their values while just changing one at a time to get the equation value?

Tags: python, derivative

I am coding an alternative partial derivative calculator. General info about the code:
In a nutshell it asks the user to enter his equation with the variables. From lab testing, he enters 7 values for each of his variables. So far it calculates the averages, averages low and averages high for each variable. The next step I need it to use the low average value of the first variable while using average value for others to get a value y1 of the equation. Then do the same but with the high average to get y2. Then compute value C1 = (y2-y1)/(Avg high - Avg Low)
Then repeat the process to get the Cs for all other variables.

```
equation = input("Enter an equation with variables: ")

variables = set()
for char in equation:
    if char.isalpha():
        variables.add(char)

values = {}
for var in variables:
    values[var] = [float(input(f"Enter a value for {var}: ")) for _ in range(7)]

averages = {}
for var, val_list in values.items():
    averages[var] = sum(val_list) / len(val_list)

uncertainties = {}
for var in variables:
    uncertainties[var] = float(input(f"Enter the uncertainty for {var}: "))

averages_low = {}
averages_high = {}
for var, avg in averages.items():
    averages_low[var] = avg - uncertainties[var]
    averages_high[var] = avg + uncertainties[var]

print("Results:")
print("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format("Variable", "Average", "Average Low", "Average High"))
for var in variables:
    print("{:<10} {:<10.2f} {:<10.2f} {:<10.2f}".format(var, averages[var], averages_low[var], averages_high[var]))
```

Here is the code so far: (I'd highly appreciate your help in completing it)

I tried adding a for loop with counters, but I am falling short for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

To complete your code and calculate the values y1, y2, and C1 for each variable, you can use nested loops.

```py
equation = input("Enter an equation with variables: ")

variables = set()
for char in equation:
    if char.isalpha():
        variables.add(char)

values = {}
for var in variables:
    values[var] = [float(input(f"Enter a value for {var}: ")) for _ in range(7)]

averages = {}
for var, val_list in values.items():
    averages[var] = sum(val_list) / len(val_list)

uncertainties = {}
for var in variables:
    uncertainties[var] = float(input(f"Enter the uncertainty for {var}: "))

averages_low = {}
averages_high = {}
for var, avg in averages.items():
    averages_low[var] = avg - uncertainties[var]
    averages_high[var] = avg + uncertainties[var]

print("Results:")
print("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format("Variable", "Average", "Average Low", "Average High"))
for var in variables:
    print("{:<10} {:<10.2f} {:<10.2f} {:<10.2f}".format(var, averages[var], averages_low[var], averages_high[var])) 

print("Calculating values y1, y2, and C1:")

y1_values = {}
y2_values = {}
C_values = {}

for var in variables:
    y1 = 0  # Initialize y1 for each variable
    y2 = 0  # Initialize y2 for each variable

    for i in range(7):
        values_copy = values.copy()
        values_copy[var] = [averages_low[var] if i == 0 else averages_high[var]]

        # Create a dictionary to hold the variable values
        variable_dict = {}
        for var_name, var_values in values_copy.items():
            variable_dict[var_name] = var_values[0]

        # Evaluate the equation using the updated values
        exec(f"y = {equation}", variable_dict)
        y = variable_dict['y']

        if i == 0:
            y1 = y
        else:
            y2 = y

    C = (y2 - y1) / (averages_high[var] - averages_low[var])

    y1_values[var] = y1
    y2_values[var] = y2
    C_values[var] = C

print("\nVariable values:")
print("{:<10} {:<10} {:<10} {:<10}".format("Variable", "y1", "y2", "C"))
for var in variables:
    print("{:<10} {:<10.2f} {:<10.2f} {:<10.2f}".format(var, y1_values[var], y2_values[var], C_values[var]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated. By adding the code and running it, I am getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 43, in <module>
    y1 = eval(equation, {}, values)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: @JeffHanderson i updated my code, you can try it again, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you again Roshid for your time. I was trying to debug the code since yesterday, but I couldn’t fix the issue unfortunately, the y1 y2 values is the issue so far. Here is the equation I am trying on: 4000*P/(3.14*D*D)
P values (7) = 813.3, Uncertainty = 2.26
D values (7) = 151.5, Uncertainty = 0.01
Using excel, for P: Avg low=811.05, Avg high=815.55, y1=45.26484054, y2=45.01397355, c = -0.05575;
For D: Avg low= 151.49, Avg high= 151.51, y1=45.14536664, y2= 45.13344864, c = -0.595899768

Comment: The fix was simple: `for i in range(7):
        values_copy = values.copy()
        values_copy[var] = [averages_low[var] if i == 0 else averages_high[var]]`

Comment: @JeffHanderson no problem, I updated my code based on your fix, if it helps please accept it as the correct answer and give an upvote for it. thanks